# Deleting selected rows in DataTable and Django

Tags: python, django, datatables

I've made a selectable rows checkbox using DataTables. I have created a good UpdateView for this so far, so editing items are good.

How can I do something like a "Delete selected items" button using that? Here's what I've done so far..

**Datatables .js script:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#table-part').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        responsive: true,
        buttons: {
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'selectAll', className: 'bg-red waves-effect' },
                { extend: 'selectNone', className: 'bg-red waves-effect' },
                { extend: 'copy', className: 'bg-red waves-effect' },
                { extend: 'csv', className: 'bg-red waves-effect' },
                { extend: 'excel', className: 'bg-green waves-effect' },
                { extend: 'print', className: 'bg-red waves-effect' },
            ],
        },
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'orderable': false,
            'className': 'select-checkbox',
            'checkboxes': {
                'selectRow': true
            }
        }],
        'select': {
            'style': 'multi',
        },
        'order': [
            [1, 'asc']
        ]
    });
});
```

Here's what it looks like:
[image]

I'm confused as to how can I use the class-based DeleteView in Django. I need something that gets all the id based on what rows I have selected, also, I need to have something like a conditional check that if I didn't select any rows to delete, the delete function won't continue, or it would be disabled, or something like that.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How did you get the edit button into the datatable?

Comment: Hello, for each <tr> I have a last <td> which has this button and an href which leads to the edit/{id} URL. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
`views.py`

```
from rest_framework import generics


class YourDeleteView(generics.DestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    queryset = YourModel.objects.all()
```

and also change your `urls.py` as below,

```
urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'endpoint/(?P<pk>\d+)', YourDeleteView.as_view())
              ]
```

So, the deletion api will be, `/api/v1/endpoint/{instance_id_to_be_deleted}/` with `HTTP DELETE` method
example:

```
import requests

requests.delete('http://host/api/v1/endpoint/1')
```